# How to Implement a Complex For-Loop + If Statement

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two data sets, each containing five-digit ZIPs.

One data set looks like this:

```
From    To      Territory

7501    10000   Unassigned
10001   10463   Agent 1
10464   10464   Unassigned
10465   11769   Agent 2
```

And a second data set that looks like this:

```
    zip5    address
1   10009   424 E 9TH ST APT 12, NEW YORK
2   10010   15 E 26TH ST APT 10C, NEW YORK
3   10013   310 GREENWICH ST, NEW YORK
4   10019   457 W 57TH ST, NEW YORK
```

I would like to write a for-loop in R that loops through the `zip5` column in the second data set, then loops through both the `From` and the `To` columns from dataset 1, checking if the `zip5` falls within the `From` and `To` range, and once it finds a match, assigns the `Territory` value from the first dataset into a new column in second dataset.

I started to try to think through the logic but quickly became overwhelmed and thought I would turn to the StackOverflow community for guidance.

Here was my initial attempt:

```
for (i in nrow(df1)){
  for(j in nrow(df2)){
    if(df1[1, "zip5"] > df2[1, "From"] & df1[1, "zip5"] <= df2[1, "To"])
      df1$newColumn = df2[j, "Territory"]
  }
}
```

Comment: for example, `10009` will meet this criteria on multiple rows of `df1`. What do you do with `newColumn` in such a scenario, when you will have multiple matching territories.

Comment: @Dij Thanks for responding. The idea is that each ZIP from `df2` will fall into only one of the ranges from `df1`. I essentially need to go through each row in `df1`, get the `zip5`, then find out which `Territory` is associated with that `zip5` in `df2` so that I can append that `Territory` to `df1`. Unfortunately, the data I have for `df2` is in the form of ranges i.e. `From` and `To` and not an exhaustive list of ZIP. Like all REAL data, it is quite ugly and a for-loop + if-statement seems like the best method forward. 

A prob is I need the `i` to stay same while `j` loops in `df2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table::foverlaps` for this:

```r
library(data.table)

dat1 <- fread(text = '
From    To      Territory
7501    10000   Unassigned
10001   10463   "Agent 1"
10464   10464   Unassigned
10465   11769   "Agent 2"')

dat2 <- fread(text = '
zip5    address
10009   "424 E 9TH ST APT 12, NEW YORK"
10010   "15 E 26TH ST APT 10C, NEW YORK"
10013   "310 GREENWICH ST, NEW YORK"
10019   "457 W 57TH ST, NEW YORK"')

# if you use your own data and it is not a data.table, then do this:
setDT(dat1)
setDT(dat2)
```

Requirements to use `foverlap`:

1. Both frames *must* have two fields, a "from" and a "to". While it might seem inane since we want to determine if "zip5" is within "From" to "To", the premise of the function is to find *overlaps* in two ranges. Instead of putting in special-case code to allow a single column in one frame, they chose (I'm inferring) to keep it general. This means we need to copy `zip5` to another column.
2. Both tables need to have their ranges as "keys". If there are other columns that are keys, then the range columns must be the last two. (And in order.)

```r
# req't 1, need a range in the second frame
dat2[, zip5copy := zip5 ]
# set keys for both
setkey(dat1, From, To)
setkey(dat2, zip5, zip5copy)
```

And the code:

```r
foverlaps(dat1, dat2)
#     zip5                        address zip5copy  From    To  Territory
# 1:    NA                           <NA>       NA  7501 10000 Unassigned
# 2: 10009  424 E 9TH ST APT 12, NEW YORK    10009 10001 10463    Agent 1
# 3: 10010 15 E 26TH ST APT 10C, NEW YORK    10010 10001 10463    Agent 1
# 4: 10013     310 GREENWICH ST, NEW YORK    10013 10001 10463    Agent 1
# 5: 10019        457 W 57TH ST, NEW YORK    10019 10001 10463    Agent 1
# 6:    NA                           <NA>       NA 10464 10464 Unassigned
# 7:    NA                           <NA>       NA 10465 11769    Agent 2
```

The default mode when there are no matches is `nomatch=NA`, meaning that the missing columns of the extra rows are filled with `NA`, as above. This is equivalent to a "full join" (one ref for joins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334). If you want just matching rows, then `foverlaps(..., nomatch=NULL)` will give you just 4 rows. (You can also reverse the order of `dat1` and `dat2`, but you might still need to use this if your actual data requires.)